# Setting paperclip defaults for prod (using S3), host name duplicates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, paperclip

My question is really two things:
1. Why is it putting my app name twice?
2. Why can't I change file path?

In production, when I set s3_host_name to "s3.amazonaws.com" image upload works, but it does not show images on views.

When I set it to "myappname.s3.amazonaws.com" It then goes here:
    http://myappname.s3.amazonaws.com/myappname/properties/avatars/4/medium.jpg

Which is still not correct because the path should be:
    http://myappname.s3.amazonaws.com/properties/avatars/4/medium.jpg

I've also tried not setting versions for the gems, and try aws v2.

All s3 permissions have been set to work as well, so when manually putting the correct path on the view the image shows up.

Gems:

```
gem "paperclip", '~> 4.3'
gem 'aws-sdk', '1.63.0' #(also tried unspecified and 2)
```

Production.rb:

```
 config.paperclip_defaults = {
    :storage => :s3,
    :s3_host_name => "myappname.s3.amazonaws.com",
    :path => "/properties/avatars/:id/:style.:extension",
    :region => 'us-west-1',
    :s3_credentials => {
      :bucket => ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME'],
      :access_key_id => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
      :secret_access_key => ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
    }
  }
```

This is the error (heroku logs):

```
OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError (hostname "myappname.myappname.s3.amazonaws.com"
```

When setting =

```
:s3_host_name => "myappname.s3.amazonaws.com"
```

BUT

```
:s3_host_name => "s3.amazonaws.com"
```

Just sets it to 's3.amazonaws.com'

My question is really two things:
1. Why is it putting my app name twice?
2. Why can't I change file path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set to this:

```
 config.paperclip_defaults = {
    :storage => :s3,
    :s3_host_name => 's3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com',
    :s3_credentials => {
      :bucket => ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME'],
      :access_key_id => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
      :secret_access_key => ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
    }
  }
```